# How to add quality to hls player (plyr.io) along with other controls(rewind, fast-forward,current-time)?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, http-live-streaming, plyr.js

I am trying to create html/php player (see this below html code)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.7.3/plyr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player">
 <video title="<?php echo $_REQUEST["q"]; ?>" preload="none" id="video" controls="controls" autoplay controls crossorigin style="width:100%;height:100%;"></video>
</div>
<script>
const controls =
[
    'play-large', 
    'play', 
    'fast-forward', 
    'progress', 
    'mute', 
    'volume', 
    'captions', 
    'settings', 
    'pip', 
    'airplay', 
    'fullscreen'
];
const player = new Plyr('#video',{controls});

setTimeout(videovisible, 4000)

function videovisible() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none'
}
var url="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8";

var video = document.getElementById('video');
 if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(url);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {     
       video.play();
    });
  }
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = url;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    video.play();
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to add controls to player (see below screenshot 1).

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL9NU.png)

But when I add quality option using [this code](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1741#issuecomment-640293554) , it only shows quality under settings button and hides all the controls (rewind, fast-forward,current-time,etc.) (see screenshot 2).

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVVmD.png)

I tried adding quality option using [this code](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1741#issuecomment-640293554), but it only shows quality under settings button and hides all the controls (rewind, fast-forward,current-time,etc.) so don't know what's wrong here. Here is the modified code.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var url = 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8';
const controls =
[
    'play-large', 
    'play', 
    'fast-forward', 
    'progress', 
    'mute', 
    'volume', 
    'captions', 
    'settings', 
    'pip', 
    'airplay', 
    'fullscreen'
];
const defaultOptions = {};
function updateQuality(newQuality) {
    window.hls.levels.forEach((level, levelIndex) => {
      if (level.height === newQuality) {
        console.log("Found quality match with " + newQuality);
        window.hls.currentLevel = levelIndex;
      }
    });
  }

 if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(url);
    //hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function(event,data) {     
       // Transform available levels into an array of integers (height values).
      var availableQualities = hls.levels.map((l) => l.height)

        // Add new qualities to option
        defaultOptions.quality = {
          default: availableQualities[0],
          options: availableQualities,
          // this ensures Plyr to use Hls to update quality level
          forced: true,        
          onChange: (e) => updateQuality(e),
        }
        controls.control ={
          controls:['play-large', 'play', 'progress', 'current-time', 'mute', 'volume', 'captions', 'settings', 'pip', 'airplay', 'fullscreen'],
        }
          

        // Initialize here
        var player = new Plyr('video',defaultOptions,controls);
        });
        hls.attachMedia(video);
  }
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = url;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(event,data) {
      
      var player = new Plyr('video',defaultOptions,controls);
     
    video.play();
    });
  }
```

How can I keep both controls and quality in player?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.